# How to slice within multiple columns?

Tags: python, integer, slice

I have a dataframe with some columns and I want to work with 3 of them (with some nan). In order to simplify, let's say that the columns are:

```
 A       B        C 
2135    87539    5255
213               
9841     126
```

The first thing I want to do is only have the first two digits of each cell, but I don't know how to do it, since the dytpe is float and I have some missing values. I want to have this:

```
 A       B        C 
21       87       52
21               
98       12
```

Then I want to replace the nan values by '103'. This part I did this way and it worked.

```
df.update(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].fillna(103))
```

So my final dataframe would be like this:

```
 A       B        C 
21       87       52
21       103      103 
98       12       103
```

I just really don't know how to do the first part, where I slice the integers. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `Series.astype` and then [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) 
to access the first 2 characters.

```
df.stack().astype(str).str[:2].unstack()
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C
0  21  87  52
1  21        
2  98  12
```

or using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) if you want get float values at the end

```
pd.to_numeric(df2.stack().astype(str).str[:2], errors='coerce').unstack()
      A     B     C
0  21.0  87.0  52.0
1  21.0   NaN   NaN
2  98.0  12.0   NaN
```

Comment: It shows me an error "'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'"

Comment: so you are not working with a dataframe but with a series, why do you say that you are working with a dataframe? Could you provide a code to simulate an example?

Comment: check `isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)` is False, you aren't working with a dataframe

Comment: I am working with the entire a datafram (df), however right now I just want to work with 3 columns of that dataframe. 'A', 'B' and 'C' are 3 columns of more than 100.

Comment: then first you select  the columns : `df[['A','B','C']].stack().astype(str).str[:2].unstack()` But the error was because you got only a column or a Series. A column of a DataFrame is a instance of `pd.Series` . But `df[['A','B','C']]` is a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do. I'm pretty sure it is not the perfect solution, but it's a vague idea and it does work. Maybe you can try to optimize it a bit.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[2135,87539,5255],[213,130,130],[9841,126,130]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'], dtype=float)
print df

#Converting to object Dtype
df[["A", "B","C"]] = df[["A","B", "C"]].astype(str) 
print df

#Storing columns in lists
listA = list(df.A)
listB = list(df.B)
listC = list(df.C)

#For generating required data
newListA = []
newListB = []
newListC = []

#Storing required data into new lists
for itemA,itemB,itemC in zip(listA,listB,listC):
    newListA.append(str(itemA[0:2]))
    newListB.append(str(itemB[0:2]))
    newListC.append(str(itemC[0:2]))

#Converting the lists to new Dataframe with float Dtype    
new_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(newListA,newListB,newListC), columns=['A','B','C'], dtype=float)
print(new_df)
```